# Multithreading issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am relatively new to objective-c, and having an issue of thread synchronization. I am trying to return an image to the user (through the user supplied image url). I am initiating the image download in a separate thread, with the thread function declared and defined in my current class. The problem is though the thread is getting executed, my image downloading functionality is not working (i.e none of the NSURLConnection methods are getting called.

My class function for initiating thread and image download is:

```
- (NSMutableData*)download:(NSString*)strURL
{
    self.strURLData=strURL;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadMethod:) toTarget:[ICacheImageDownloadMgr class] withObject:self];
    //Here ICacheImageDownloadMgr is my current class
    while(!bCompletionFlag)
    {
        if(bCompletionFlag)//bCompletionFlag is set to TRUE in NSURLConnection::connectionDidFinishLoading method after successful image download
        {
            return currentData;
        }
    }
}
```

My only motive here is to return "currentData" after the image download process has completed, to the user.
And the thread method declared in my current class (i.e., ICacheImageDownloadMgr) is:

```
+ (void) threadMethod:(ICacheImageDownloadMgr*)param
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    if(param.currentData)
    {
        [param.currentData release];
        param.currentData=nil;
    }
    param.currentData   = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithLength:0];  

    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:param.strURLData];
    NSURLRequest *URLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: myURL];
    param.urlcon = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:URLRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [myURL release];

    param.dataLock = [[NSLock alloc]init];

    while(!param.bCompletionFlag)
    {
        if([param.dataLock tryLock])
        {
            if(param.bCompletionFlag)//bCompletionFlag is set to TRUE in NSURLConnection::connectionDidFinishLoading method after successful image download, along with NSLock unlock call
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    [pool release];

}
```

Please let me know as to what I am doing wrong here? It seems both my threads here are into blocking and that's why my NSURLConnection methods are not getting called. Again, as stated earlier, my only aim is to return "currentData" to the user.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

`param.urlcon = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:URLRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];`

will start an async connection which relies on delegate methods to let you manage the ongoing transfer. You are not providing the implementation of your delegate methods, so I cannot say what is happening there,

On another note, since you are starting a thread for your requests, you could simplify your life and make them synchronous (and actually I think this is what you were aiming at in the first place), so you do not have to deal with the delegate protocol. You can use the

```
+ sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:
```

method for that, e.g.:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:URLRequest returningResponse:&yourResponse error:&yourError];
```

Comment: thanks for your advise on using sendSynchronousRequest. That's exactly what I was intending to do. My code is working now. However, I am still not able to understand as why my implementation of the NSURLConnection delegate methods (like didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData, and connectionDidFinishLoading) were not being called in my code? I guess as mentioned by tia, the while loop in my main threading was blocking the app itself.

Comment: You should have created a run loop in your thread I think... in your thread you enter a while that does not allow the response to be processed I think... you may read this:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say but it's wrong at too many places.

1. You are saturating main thread with tight `while` loop in `download:`, which is not good because the other thread will have less CPU time to work.
2. The `while` loop in `download:` practically blocks main thread, which will make your UI unresponsive until the loop is over.
3. There is no guarantee that the loop will ever finish.
4. `NSURLConnection` starting is already asynchronous, so you might need no threading.
5. The `ICacheImageDownloadMgr` properties is `retain` or `assign`? I don't think you did the memory management correctly, and that will result in memory leaks or crash.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things

1. Use NSOperation instead of Thread, even better have a look at [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).
2. Starting a new Thread and then waiting for it to finish is a waste of a thread. WHat you need to do is have the request handling done in one thread and then have it reqport back when it is finished with the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to work with NSURLConnection.
As sergio mentioned, NSURLConnection works with delegates method that return the responses and data, which you should collect.

NSURLConnection creates a background thread itself for its asynchronous operation and sends its delegate methods back to the main thread, so you don't actually need to create a background thread yourself.

Also, if you're going to wait for a flag that tells that the connection is finished in a while loop, there's no background benefit to it at all. In addition, you application will beach-ball until the connection is finished, since you don't return control to the Run Loop.